# How to Group icons in TinyMce 4

Tags: tinymce-4

In TinyMCE 3x we used have setting something like below:

**theme_advanced_buttons1:**

**theme_advanced_buttons2:**

etc ..
This can be used in tinymce.init to group icons.

how can I do the same in tinymce 4? Is there a way to manually change/add grouping through tinymce.init?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TinyMCE 4 you can pass an array to the `toolbar` configuration setting to allow for multiple rows of toolbar buttons.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#toolbar
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#usingmultipletoolbars

For example:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  toolbar: [
    'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | link image',
    'alignleft aligncenter alignright'
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.